# can't retrieve cordova forked plugins from github

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, github, cordova-plugins

I can't figure out what is going on here.  `cordova plugin add` is working for a project on the dev computer but not working on the prod computer.  The plugins that are failing are forked plugins...but best I can tell it shouldn't be a problem...yet it is.

Dev computer:

```
  ionic/cli-utils: 1.19.1
  ionic (ionic CLI): 3.19.1
  ionic frame: ionic1 1.0.0
  cordova (cli): 8.0.0
  gulp cli: v 3.9.1
  gulp local: 3.9.1
  node: 6.9.1
  npm: 5.6.0
```

Prod computer:

```
  Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
  Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
  Ionic Version: 1.3.4
  Cordova CLI: 8.0.0
  Cordova-Android: 7.1.1
  Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
  Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
  Node Version: v6.10.3
```

On the Dev computer, I can add forked github plugins to my project, but I can't on my Prod computer.  On the prod I get the error:

```
c:\myapp>cordova plugin add https://github.com/amritk/cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="851844754851253" --variable APP_NAME="Whipster"
(node:3988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/amritk/cordova-plugin-facebook4 via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/amritk/cordova-plugin-facebook4.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/amritk/cordova-plugin-facebook4.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\RPO\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-082T21_38_50_110Z-debug.log
```

Its happening on two other forked plugins too.

Comment: What version are your PROD Cordova libraries? Specifically, `cordova-android`, `cordova-ios` and `cordova-browser`? Also, what version is your Phonegap?

Comment: Try removing the `https:` that worked for me once before?

Comment: @ObsidianAge  - on these computers its only cordova-android, both are at 7.1.1.  I am not using phonegap, just cordova.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was working until I upgrade the Prod machine from cordova@7.0.1 to cordova@8.0.0.  I think the ionic v1 installation on the prod box was using git v1.90.0.windows.1 and I force upgraded it to git 2.18.0.windows.1.

Now git works again.